# Jquery Deferred Not reaching last .then

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

I have a sequence of functions that must be executed. They all execute sequentially except the last one. d1 executes, d2 executes, d3 executes then the code inside the done function executes before the resolve of d4. Can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var d1 = functiond1();
    var d2 = functiond2();
    var d3 = functiond3();
    var d4 = functiond4();

    d1.then(d2).then(d3).then(d4).done(function() {

    //Code here does not wait for d4 to end before executing
    //HELP! 

    });
});

function functiond1() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    //Do stuff here
    //Works in sequence

    dfd.resolve();
    return dfd.promise();
}


function functiond2() {

    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    params = jQuery.param({
        'parm1': 1,
        'parm2': 2,
        'parm3': 3
    });


    jQuery.getJSON($.webMethoJSONGet1, params).done(function(data) {

        //Do stuff here
        //Works in sequence

        dfd.resolve();

    });

    return dfd.promise();
}

function functiond3() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    //Do stuff here
    //Works in sequence

    dfd.resolve();
    return dfd.promise();
}

function functiond4() {

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    params = jQuery.param({
        'parm1': 1,
        'parm2': 2,
        'parm3': 3
    });

    jQuery.getJSON($.webMethoJSONGet2, params).done(function(data) {

        //Do stuff here
        //does not work in sequence

        dfd.resolve();

    });

    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, please indent your code readably. I've run the code through jsbeautifier for you.

Comment: Great tip. Done as requested. Any tips in regards to the code?

Comment: Why did you indent all the code so far? I'd already fixed it for you, now more of it is off to the right than is necessary. I've re-fixed it.

Comment: The deferred chain goes inside the $(document).ready(). Thats the last fix'.

Comment: Why doesn't funtiond4 just return the ajaxPromise? Nesting promises like that is considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the ajaxPromise.

Comment: No you didn't. Your `getJson.done()` returns a promise and should be what your function returns. Nesting another promise within that defeats the purpose of using promises entirely.

Comment: +1 to what Jason says - you should just `return jQuery.getJSON(...)` in each of your functions (unless the method doesn't already return a promise by itself).  Chances are that `functiond3` is failing somehow, but that failure is obscured by the nest promise that always resolves (even if the JSON call fails) causing `functiond4` to be triggered too soon.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do with those promises. You first call all 4 functions, and then you try to chain them with a bunch of `then` callbacks. If you want to sequentially chain them together it should look like this:

```
functiond1()
.then(functiond2)
.then(functiond3)
.then(functiond4)
.done(function() { /* blah */ });
```

If you just want a result after all have completed you can use `$.when`

```
$.when(functiond1(), functiond2(), functiond3(), functiond4())
.then(function(resultd1, resultd2, resultd3, resultd4) { /* blah */ });
```

On another note, in your functions you create promises that are resolved inside the `done` callback of another promise which is unnecessary. The `$.getJSON.done()` calls return a promise themselves so an additional promise is not needed. Just return the promise returned from `done()`.

Sorry, I haven't messed much with jQuery deferred objects, but they appear similiar enough to standard Promises.

Comment: no, that's wrong - you have to pass a function reference to `.then`, not the result of calling that function immediately

Comment: @Alnitak I fixed it to defer calling the function inside `then`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i'm calling for functions, which each return a promise that should not continue to the next one until the previous is resolved, but the last one does not wait till the resolve.

Answer (score 0):

To run the functions in sequence, you need to pass *references* to the functions within the `.then` chain, and not the *results* of calling those functions.

e.g.

```
var d1 = functiond1;   // NB: no ()
...

d1.then(d2).then(d3).then(d4).done(...);    
functiond1().then(functiond2).then(functiond3).then(functiond4).done(...)
```

The ultimate cause of your problem is that invoking `d4` straight away will cause its resolved promise to pass-thru to `.done` immediately irrespective of the state of the earlier part of the `.then` chain.

You should also not wrap your JSON functions with additional promises, since `$.getJSON` already returns a promise that will be *rejected* if the AJAX query fails:

```
function functiond4() {
    ...
    return $.getJSON(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Pay no attention to the function names. I changed them from the originals before i posted the question to emphasize on the function order.  Trust that those are not the names I'm using.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same issue on a project, this solution with an array works well:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pr = [];
    var d1 = functiond1();
    var d2 = functiond2();
    var d3 = functiond3();
    var d4 = functiond4();

    function functiond1() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        pr.push(dfd);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').append('1 resolved <br>');
            dfd.resolve();
        }, 2000);
    }


    function functiond2() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        pr.push(dfd);

        params = jQuery.param({
            'parm1': 1,
            'parm2': 2,
            'parm3': 3
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').append('2 resolved <br>');            
            dfd.resolve();
        }, 3000);
    }

    function functiond3() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        pr.push(dfd);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').append('3 resolved <br>');
            dfd.resolve();
        }, 1000);
    }

    function functiond4() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        pr.push(dfd);

        params = jQuery.param({
            'parm1': 1,
            'parm2': 2,
            'parm3': 3
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').append('4 resolved <br>');
            dfd.resolve();
        }, 50);
    }

    $.when.apply($, pr).then(function() {
        // do something
        $('body').append('proceed with code execution');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm validating.

Comment: You are welcome, please share your code in case it doesn't work.

Comment: NB: this code will make _all four_ functions run at once, doing their async stuff in parallel, and only resolving once they've all finished.

Comment: So it does - I misread that.   That's actually his problem, then

Comment: @Alnitak whit this code you can achieve exactly what ricardo wanted: -> Run all functions independently -> Register them in the promise collection -> Once all promises are resolved, proceed with some logic

Comment: Thanks for the responses. What i would like is for them to run in sequence, f1, then f2, then f3, then f4.

Comment: Why do you wanna use promises then? For code readability? The idea behind promises is that code can be executed async but you only proceed "when" as soon all promises are resolved. In your case you could simply call d2 inside d1, d3 inside d2 and d4 inside d3?

Comment: @Spidi no, the fundamental idea behind promises is the `.then` call for _sequential chaining of asynchronous operations_.  `$.when` is just a special case for synchronising multiple chains of promises.